# Error en RestApi Node + Express

Tags: nodejs, rest, express

**Estoy consumiendo un api y necesito exponerla.**

```
router.get('/heroes', (req, res) => {

request('API', {json: true}, (err, res, req) => {

if(err) return console.log('error:', err);

console.log('statusCode:', res.statusCode);

console.log("respuesta:" + JSON.stringify(res['body']));
}),

 res.status(res.statusCode).send(JSON.stringify(res['body'])
 )
});
```

**La API esta construida en un JSON que tiene un objeto body adentro. Necesito exponer al objeto Body.**

**En la consola estoy viendo el objeto de forma correcta pero cuando quiero exponerlo no me deja ni tampoco veo errores.**

**Me pueden ayudar?
Muchas gracias !**

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos cosas mal con tu *handler*: la ocultación de los argumentos del handler y la respuesta que emites fuera de la petición.

Primero, provee argumentos con nombres distintos en el *callback* de la petición. Es muy mala práctica usar los mismos nombres de argumentos de funciones más altas en las internas.

Segundo, estás enviando la respuesta al cliente **fuera del callback de la petición**. JavaScript es un lenguaje con un concepto muy marcado de asincronía; así que te recomiendo leer al respecto.

En términos generales, el stack **no tiene forma de saber cuando la petición ha sido resuelta** debido a que una petición HTTP es asíncrona, causando que el callback de la petición pueda ser ejecutado antes o después que el envío de la respuesta del route.

Lo que tienes que hacer es mover esta línea hacia dentro del callback de la petición:

```
res.status(res2.statusCode).send(JSON.stringify(res2.body))
```